# How to call JavaScript function from a .HTML file to a .JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've been working on a .js and .html file and in my .js file, I want to call to a function that's located in the .html file.

This is the function in the .html file that I want to be called to:

```
    <script>
        function themeChange4() {
            document.getElementById("theStyle").style = "";
        }
    </script>
```

This is where I want the function to be called to in my .js file:

```
add_icon_not_via_filesystem({
    title: "Vending Machine",
    icon: "Soda",
    open: themeChange4,
});
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: You can call the function directly in your .js file without any extra code like this `themeChange4()`

Comment: You’re not actually calling the function, you’re passing it as a value. Nevertheless, calling or passing it as a value, you just need to make sure that the script that references the function is loaded after the definition of the function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood You want from HTML

```
  <script src="js.js"></script>
  <script>
  function themeChange4(){
     add_icon_not_via_filesystem(); 
  }
themeChange4();
 </script>
```

to call

```
function add_icon_not_via_filesystem(){
 alert('This');
 }
```

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I wanted a function from a .HTML file to be used in a .js file.